# How to wait until all the tasks finish before returning from method in C#

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

In my Web API Controller **MyController** there is a call to my service class

```
   [HttpPost]
   Route("groupmembershipvalidate")]
   public IHttpActionResult PostGroupMembershipValidate(ListGroupMembershipUploadInput ListGroupMembershipUploadInput) 
   {

    //perform some tasks

    var searchResults =  ts.validateDetails(gmvi);

    return Ok(searchResults);

   }
```

Now this **validateDetails** service class needs to run some tasks parallely and needs to wait for all the results to come back and then only  return back .

```
        var tasks = new Task[]
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => gd.validateChapterCodeDetails(_input1)),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => gd.validateGroupCodeDetails(_input1)),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => gd.validateMasterIdDetails(_input1))
        };

       var things = Task.WhenAll(tasks);

       //Some tasks

       return result;
```

The result returned is not computed until all the tasks return their results. But when Task.WhenAll(tasks) is hit , it immediately moves to the next few lines and returned to  **PostGroupMembershipValidate** controller method .

How to wait before returning values and return only after getting all the values ?

Comment: "*How to **wait** until **all** the **task**s finish*" => `Task.WaitAll`

Comment: Your tasks did not return any result. What result are you expecting to return? things is also a simple Task instance on which you can wait but without any further result value. So clarify your question

Comment: Be aware of the difference between Task.WhenAll and Task.WaitAll. WaitAll returns void. The next statement is executed after all tasks are finished. WhenAll returns an awaitable Task. As long as you don't await for the task your code will continue until you await for the result of the task. This has the advantage that your callers won't freeze as long as you are awaiting. The disadvantage is that you have to declare your function async. See Stephen Cleary about this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When all can be used to create a new task which completes when all tasks in it completes, you can then proceed fetching results out of that task using the regular async patterns.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx

So 
    //If your validation results are strings:
    Task[] tasks = ...
    var things = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Alternatively WaitAll can be used, but if you need to do work on the output that is an awkward aproach here. IMO staying in the async context is always better anyways.

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
foreach(var t in tasks) DoSomething(t.Result);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx

Besides, it blocks the current thread AFAIK.

---

A more complete console example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/JMLHxR

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    private static int counter = 0;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        var tasks = new Task<object>[]
        {
            // If your target method returns a task.
            //  - note: A Proxy or similar approach will probably be more readable.
            CreateTask(rnd.Next(500,2000)).ContinueWith(t => (object)t.Result),
            CreateOtherTask(rnd.Next(500,2000)).ContinueWith(t => (object)t.Result),
            CreateTask(rnd.Next(500,2000)).ContinueWith(t => (object)t.Result),
            CreateOtherTask(rnd.Next(500,2000)).ContinueWith(t => (object)t.Result),

            //If your target method is syncronious.
            Task.Run(() => (object)CreateSimple()),
            Task.Run(() => (object)CreateMessage()),
            Task.Run(() => (object)CreateSimple()),
            Task.Run(() => (object)CreateMessage())
        };      

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        foreach(var t in tasks)
            Console.WriteLine(t.Result);

        // They are already completed here, but just to show the syntax.
        // .Result should obvisously be awaited instead.
        var all = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result;
        foreach(var result in all)
            Console.WriteLine(result);
    }


    private static string CreateSimple()
    {
        int id = Program.counter++;
        return "Task [" + id + "] delayed: NONE";
    }

    private static Message CreateMessage()
    {
        return new Message(CreateSimple());
    }

    private static async Task<string> CreateTask(int delay)
    {
        int id = Program.counter++;
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        return "Task [" + id + "] delayed: " + delay;
    }

    private static async Task<Message> CreateOtherTask(int delay)
    {
        int id = Program.counter++;
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        return new Message("Task [" + id + "] delayed: " + delay);
    }

    public class Message {
        private string message;

        public Message(string msg) { message = msg; }

        public override string ToString(){ return message; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But when I do `var tasks = await Task.WhenAll(tasks) ` it says cannot assign void to implicitly typed local variables.

Comment: You currently use Task[] which indicates that your tasks are void, if you need something returned from them you should use Task<something>[]

Comment: The tasks have varying return types ... and auto conversion from IEnumerable<ReturnedType> to IEnumerable<Object> not working.

Comment: Updated the complete example with a rather "quick-n-dirty" way of dealing with that for two cases. In your case, it should be enough to cast the return of your validation methods to object inside the lambda you provide to the task as the later part of the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started");
        Task.WaitAll(task1(), task2());
        Console.WriteLine("Ended");
    }

    static async Task<string> task1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started task1");
        var task = await Task.Run(() => { return "task1"; });
        Console.WriteLine("Ended task1");
        return task;
    }

    static async Task<string> task2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started task2");
        var task = await Task.Run(() => { return "task2"; });
        Console.WriteLine("Ended task2");
        return task;
    }
}
```

produces this output:

```
Started
Started task1
Ended task1
Started task2
Ended task2
Ended
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `var things = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` shows me compilation error saying 'cannot assign void to implicitly typed local variables`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this

```
public class Sample1
{

    public void Run()
    {
        foreach ( var item in Validate( "foobar" ).Result )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( item );
        }
    }

    // starts some result producing tasks
    // await all of them 
    // return the result of each task
    public async Task<IEnumerable> Validate( string input )
    {
        var tasks = new Task<object>[ ] {
            Task.Run( ()=> (object) ValidateFoo(input) ),
            Task.Run( ()=> (object) ValidateBar(input) ),
        };

        return await Task.WhenAll( tasks );
    }

    private string ValidateFoo( string input )
    {
        return "foo";
    }

    private bool ValidateBar( string input )
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var task1 = T1();
var task2 = T2();

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

Comment: when it encounters `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);` it again moves forward to the next few lines without getting and waiting for the results from those tasks and eventually returns. What to do ?

Comment: check the result you get: var results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);